# Docker changes are not reflected in local filesystem and viceversa

Tags: docker

I have simple docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  server-opencv:
    build:
      context: ./server-opencv
      dockerfile: ./../docker/Dockerfile-server-opencv
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./server-opencv:/app/src
    ports:
      - "8082:3000"
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
```

Current file structure is:

```
- docker-compose.yml
- server-opencv
    - here_is_content_of_server
- docker
    - Dockerfile-server-opencv
```

In dockerfile-server-opencv I have this:

```
FROM justadudewhohacks/opencv-nodejs:node9-opencv3.4.1-contrib
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm -i install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Docker works correctly, if I run `docker-compose build --no-cache` it is builded and after that if I run `docker-compose up` then container is attached. BUT if in server I create some files, I cannot see them locally in my hosting computer filesystem (I would apprechiate if in folder `server-opencv` will be live files from docker). Also if I change something in my local computer in folder `server-opencv`, docker doesnt reflect this changes, I have again build and up container, and after that changes are applied.

What am I missing? I'm running on MacOS

Comment: Are you expecting the node application to self refresh or just the mounted data? As a side note, running the docker image in the way you are is weird because you are mounting on `/app` the whole root folder (`.`), hence `/app/server-opencv` is entirely mounted (including the`node_modules`)

Comment: I updated question, same issue

Comment: I am still confused though: you are mounting in `/app/src` although the app is running on `/app`. I suspect that the docker mounting is indeed working as intended (you can use `docker exec -it [container-name] sh` to inspect the container and run `ls -la /app/src` to check if the listed files and directories are correctly mounted and updated), what I think is wrong is where it is mounted or what you are expecting to happen: if you expect the server to self-update (and run again) when any javascript file changes, this is not going to happen, you need nodemon for that.

Comment: I'm mounting source of whole server to app/src, and then in docker-file Iˇm copying package.json to /app. I can connect to docker, when ti si running, all folder structure is correct, problem is that it is not "live updated" with local filesystem and vice versa